# Using multiple ViewModel's in WinRT

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime

**OS**: Windows 8.1
**IDE**: VS 2013 Express for Windows
**Project**: Universal
**Target**: Windows 8.1, Phone 8.1
**IoC**: MEF

My Windows App is being based on this Guideline "[Hierarchical navigation, start to finish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440585.aspx)" on the **Windows Dev Center**.  I'm using MEF to inject my ViewModels into Views.

The **MainPage** is in the **.Shared Project** and the **HubPage**, **ItemPage** and **SectionPage** are in there perspective **Window** and **Phone Projects**.

Each **Page** has its own **ViewModel** located in an *assembly* called **UILogic**.  During startup all **ViewModels** are successfully injected into there **Views**.  However looking at the **Immediate Window** I get this *Binding Errors*:

**Windows 8.1**

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'HubSectionHeaderCommand' property not found on 'NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='HubSectionHeaderCommand' DataItem='NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.InvokeCommandAction' (Name='null'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'DefaultDataModel' property not found on 'NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='DefaultDataModel' DataItem='NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource' (Name='null'); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'NavigationHelper' property not found on 'NathsarTS.Views.HubPage'. BindingExpression: Path='NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand' DataItem='NathsarTS.Views.HubPage'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='backButton'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Section3Items' property not found on 'NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='Section3Items' DataItem='NathsarTS.UILogic.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel, NathsarTS.UILogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection' (Name='null'); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

The **MainPage** looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
```

The **HubPage** looks like this which is navigated too during startup:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
...
..
<Hub >
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SectionHeaderClick">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HubSectionHeaderCommand}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Hub.Header>
        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            ...
            ..
            <Button  x:Name="backButton" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                Margin="0,0,39,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
            ...
            ..
        </Grid>
    </Hub.Header>
    ...
    ..
    <HubSection IsHeaderInteractive="True" 
                DataContext="{Binding Section3Items}" 
                d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[3], Source={d:DesignData Source=../NathsarTS.Shared/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
                x:Uid="Section3Header" Header="Section 3" Padding="40,40,40,32">
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridView
                x:Name="itemGridView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                Margin="-9,-14,0,0"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310x260ItemTemplate}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HubSectionGridItemCommand}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    ...
    ..
</Hub>
```

My Bindings are being reported as not being found on the **MainPageViewModel**, but they are defined in the **HubPageViewModel**.

I have **MEF** injecting the **ViewModels** this way:

```
[Export(typeof(HubPage))]
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
{
public HubPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Debug.WriteLine("HubPage InitializeComponent");
}

[Import]
public NathsarTS.UILogic.Interfaces.IHubPageViewModel ViewModel
{
    set
    {
        this.DataContext = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return DataContext as NathsarTS.UILogic.Interfaces.IHubPageViewModel;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when a part's imports have been satisfied and it is safe to use.
/// </summary>
[OnImportsSatisfied]
public void OnImportsSatisfied()
{
    // IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification is useful when you want to coordinate doing some work
    // with imported parts independent of when the UI is visible.
    Debug.WriteLine("HubPage OnImportsSatisfied instantiation");

    //NathsarTS.UILogic.Interfaces.IObservableService ObservableService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NathsarTS.UILogic.Interfaces.IObservableService>();
    this.ViewModel.NavigationHelper = new NathsarTS.Common.Logic.NavigationHelper(this);
    this.ViewModel.NavigationHelper.LoadState += this.ViewModel.NavigationHelperLoadState;
}
}
```

**ViewModels** per **PageView** isn't permitted in **WinRT**?

**IN ADDTION**: I've also notice this during startup, the HubPage is being Initialize twice.  Why?:

```
MainPage InitializeComponent
PropertiesService instantiation
MainPageViewModel instantiation
MainPage OnImportsSatisfied instantiation
HubPage InitializeComponent
HubPageViewModel instantiation
HubPage OnImportsSatisfied instantiation
HubPage InitializeComponent
HubPage OnNavigatedTo instantiation
```

This is what I'm doing during startup:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    this._configuration.WithAssembly(typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .WithAssembly(typeof(NathsarTS.UILogic.UILogicBusinessLogic).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .WithAssembly(typeof(NathsarTS.Common.CommonBusinessLogic).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .WithAssembly(typeof(NathsarTS.ODSDocuments.ODSDocumentsBusinessLogic).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    this._compositionHost = this._configuration.CreateContainer();

    await ShowWindow(args);
}

private async Task ShowWindow(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage mainPage = Window.Current.Content as MainPage;
    Frame rootFrame = null;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (mainPage == null)
    {
        mainPage = _compositionHost.GetExport<MainPage>();
    }

    // Retrieve the root Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
    // Don't change the name of "rootFrame" in MainPage.xaml unless you change it here to match.
    rootFrame = (Frame)mainPage.FindName("rootFrame");
    if (rootFrame != null)
    {
        // Associate the frame with a SuspensionManager key.
        SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");

        // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
        rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate
            try
            {
                await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
            }
            catch (SuspensionManagerException)
            {
                //Something went wrong restoring state.
                //Assume there is no state and continue
            }
        }

        // Place the main page in the current Window.
        Window.Current.Content = mainPage;

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            HubPage hubPage = _compositionHost.GetExport<HubPage>();
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(hubPage.GetType(), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

    }

    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Thanks for you help!..

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix my duplicates and properly have the correct **ViewModel** connected to the **PageView**.  The problem was the .*Navigation* for 1) keep re-initializing the **Page** constructor after **MEF** does its initializing, 2) for some reason the **HubPage** **DataContext** gets lost.

So, this is how I solved it:

```
protected override async Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnLaunchApplicationAsync...");

    MainPage mainPage = _compositionHost.GetExport<MainPage>();
    Window.Current.Content = mainPage;
    Frame rootFrame = (Frame)mainPage.FindName("rootFrame");

    if (rootFrame != null)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            HubPage hubPage = _compositionHost.GetExport<HubPage>();
            rootFrame.Content = hubPage;
        }
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
    await Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Instead of using the .*Navigation* in the initial startup I just assigned the **Page** *Type* to the .*Content*.